# Laravel Почему цикл кладет на каждом этапе в базу значение, из предыдущего цикла, хотя ничего выполнятся не должно?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, if

```
public function updateSpecializations(Request $request)
{
    if(AjaxRequest::ajax()) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'values.*' => 'numeric|min:1'
        ]);

        $values = Input::get('values');
        if(null !== $values){
            $values = array_slice($values,0,5);
        }
        $user = Auth::user();
        if(count($values) == 0)
        {
            $user->specializations()->whereNotIn('sub_category_id', [0])->delete();
        }
        else
        {
            foreach ($values as $key => &$value){
                echo '['.$key."!".$value.']';
                if($key < 5){
                    $doubledSpecializations = Specialization::where('sub_category_id',$value)->where('user_id',$user->id)->count();

                    if($doubledSpecializations != 0)
                    {
                        //$user->specializations()->whereIn('sub_category_id', $values)->delete();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //TODO: Почему он может на каждом этапе цикла положить в базу?
                        $subCategory = SubCategory::findOrFail($value);
                        $specialization = new Specialization;
                        echo "->".$value."|".$key.":";
                        $subCategory->specializations()->save($specialization);
                        $user->specializations()->save($specialization);

                        $specialization->save();
                    }
                }
            }
            $user->specializations()->whereNotIn('sub_category_id', $values)->delete();
        }
        return response()->json(['message' => 'saved!', 'values' => $values]);
    }
}
```

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax посылал 2 запроса сразу, добавил ему таймаут в 500 милисекунд, чтобы не спамил, а то база не успевала реагировать.

> Сам цикл выполнялся должным образом и сохранение модели не сохраняло
>   копию, 2 ajax запроса запускали паралельно 2 php в котором проверялись
>   записи в базе (одновременно не находили) и записывали два значения паралельно